# Can Asmoranomardicadaistinaculdacar be cast by Aluren or by Cascade effects? (Modern Horizons 2 Spoilers)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Asmoranomardicadaistinaculdacar is a card recently spoiled for Modern Horizons 2.

[image]

Notable on the card is a lack of an actual mana cost.  The card's first line is clearly intended for how to properly cast the card.

> As long as you've discarded a card this turn you may pay [B/R] to cast this spell.

Does [Aluren](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aluren) or cards with Cascade ([Shardless Agent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shardless%20Agent), for example) allow you to cast Asmoranomardicadaistinaculdacar?

Comment: Aside: [Living End](https://strategy.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/home/deck-highlight-modern-living-end/) is a Tier 2-ish Modern deck which relies on cascading into its no casting cost namesake card.

Comment: The sheer length of the card name made me click to view this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, you may pay alternative costs to cast Asmoranomardicadaistinaculdacar, and "without paying its mana cost" is an alternative cost.**

> 118.6. Some objects have no mana cost. This represents an unpayable cost. An ability can also have an unpayable cost if its cost is based on the mana cost of an object with no mana cost. Attempting to cast a spell or activate an ability that has an unpayable cost is a legal action. However, attempting to pay an unpayable cost is an illegal action.

> 118.6a If an unpayable cost is increased by an effect or an additional cost is imposed, the cost is still unpayable. If an alternative cost is applied to an unpayable cost, including an effect that allows a player to cast a spell without paying its mana cost, the alternative cost may be paid.

Note that "As long as you've discarded a card this turn you may pay [B/R] to cast this spell." also represents an alternative cost, so that's already a hint regarding alternative costs.

Comment: And I'm assuming, for the sake of these effects, Asmoranomardicadaistinaculdacar's CMC is 0 because he doesn't have one, correct?

Comment: Correct, although the term CMC is obsolete and is now called mana value: 202.3a The mana value of an object with no mana cost is 0

Comment: now that I'm reading the *new* oracle text for Aluren, they've changed it to say Mana Value instead of the Converted Mana Cost that it says on the cardboard.